# Why calling libav* library doesn't have same quality as ffmpeg command line?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using the ffmpeg 3 to do the video format conversion, it works fine when I use the command line mode, but when I call the libav* library, I get a audio quality loss problem (there is a lot of noises in the audio).

Here are the two files:

**[mv.webm - original file](http://www.megafileupload.com/nrXk/mv.webm) 

[mv2.mp4 converted with libarary , a lot of noises](http://www.megafileupload.com/nrXm/mv1-noise.mp4)**

Here is the probe information for the mv.webm:

```
$ ffprobe mv.webm
ffprobe version N-79826-g64fd62d Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.1 (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) 20160413
  configuration: --prefix=/home/seaguest/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/home/seaguest/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/seaguest/ffmpeg_build/lib --enable-gpl --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 24.100 / 55. 24.100
  libavcodec     57. 39.100 / 57. 39.100
  libavformat    57. 36.100 / 57. 36.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 45.100 /  6. 45.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'mv.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.36.100
  Duration: 00:00:30.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 935 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: vp8, yuv420p, 640x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
    Stream #0:1: Audio: vorbis, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
```

I checked the log printed by command line mode and calling code mode, the setting looks like the same, here are the logs:

```
$ ffmpeg -i mv.webm -c:a aac -c:v libx264  mv.mp4
ffmpeg version N-79826-g64fd62d Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.1 (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) 20160413
  configuration: --prefix=/home/seaguest/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/home/seaguest/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/seaguest/ffmpeg_build/lib --enable-gpl --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 24.100 / 55. 24.100
  libavcodec     57. 39.100 / 57. 39.100
  libavformat    57. 36.100 / 57. 36.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 45.100 /  6. 45.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'mv.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.36.100
  Duration: 00:00:30.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 935 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: vp8, yuv420p, 640x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
    Stream #0:1: Audio: vorbis, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
[libx264 @ 0x3e5d880] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x3e5d880] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x3e5d880] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x3e5d880] 264 - core 148 r2643 5c65704 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[mp4 @ 0x3e2f680] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
    Last message repeated 1 times
Output #0, mp4, to 'mv.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.36.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 25 fps, 12800 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.39.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.39.100 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (vp8 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (vorbis (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  750 fps=229 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2508kB time=00:00:30.02 bitrate= 684.5kbits/s speed=9.17x
video:2023kB audio:459kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.052857%
[libx264 @ 0x3e5d880] frame I:11    Avg QP:15.29  size: 20395
[libx264 @ 0x3e5d880] frame P:345   Avg QP:20.93  size:  4350
[libx264 @ 0x3e5d880] frame B:394   Avg QP:23.55  size:   879
[libx264 @ 0x3e5d880] consecutive B-frames: 25.2%  3.2% 33.2% 38.4%
[libx264 @ 0x3e5d880] mb I  I16..4: 44.1% 32.5% 23.4%
[libx264 @ 0x3e5d880] mb P  I16..4:  1.5%  3.6%  0.6%  P16..4: 28.9% 11.2%  4.7%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:49.5%
[libx264 @ 0x3e5d880] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8: 27.4%  2.0%  0.4%  direct: 0.8%  skip:69.3%  L0:40.0% L1:53.3% BI: 6.7%
[libx264 @ 0x3e5d880] 8x8 transform intra:52.6% inter:74.9%
[libx264 @ 0x3e5d880] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 57.5% 68.6% 35.9% inter: 10.6% 11.9% 2.6%
[libx264 @ 0x3e5d880] i16 v,h,dc,p: 36% 42%  7% 15%
[libx264 @ 0x3e5d880] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 15% 23% 15% 6%  7%  7% 10%  7% 10%
[libx264 @ 0x3e5d880] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 20% 27% 14% 6%  8%  7%  7%  6%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x3e5d880] i8c dc,h,v,p: 46% 34% 11%  9%
[libx264 @ 0x3e5d880] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x3e5d880] ref P L0: 63.9% 20.8% 11.2%  4.1%
[libx264 @ 0x3e5d880] ref B L0: 93.1%  6.1%  0.8%
[libx264 @ 0x3e5d880] ref B L1: 95.8%  4.2%
[libx264 @ 0x3e5d880] kb/s:552.32
[aac @ 0x3e5ec00] Qavg: 3030.804


$ ffprobe mv.mp4
ffprobe version N-79826-g64fd62d Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.1 (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) 20160413
  configuration: --prefix=/home/seaguest/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/home/seaguest/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/seaguest/ffmpeg_build/lib --enable-gpl --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 24.100 / 55. 24.100
  libavcodec     57. 39.100 / 57. 39.100
  libavformat    57. 36.100 / 57. 36.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 45.100 /  6. 45.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'mv.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.36.100
  Duration: 00:00:30.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 684 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 552 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

For the calling code mode:

```
$ go run transcode.go mv.webm mv1.mp4
# github.com/3d0c/gmf
../packet.go: In function ‘_cgo_3c42eeb63b1e_Cfunc_avcodec_decode_audio4’:
../packet.go:87:2: warning: ‘avcodec_decode_audio4’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
 func (this *Packet) decode(cc *CodecCtx, frame *Frame) (*Frame, bool, int, error) {
  ^
In file included from ../packet.go:7:0:
/home/seaguest/ffmpeg_build/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:4685:5: note: declared here
 int avcodec_decode_audio4(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVFrame *frame,
     ^
../packet.go: In function ‘_cgo_3c42eeb63b1e_Cfunc_avcodec_decode_video2’:
../packet.go:104:2: warning: ‘avcodec_decode_video2’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   }
  ^
In file included from ../packet.go:7:0:
/home/seaguest/ffmpeg_build/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:4734:5: note: declared here
 int avcodec_decode_video2(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVFrame *picture,
     ^
[libx264 @ 0x2d82400] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x2d82400] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x2d82400] 264 - core 148 r2643 5c65704 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[mp4 @ 0x2d480c0] Using AVStream.codec.time_base as a timebase hint to the muxer is deprecated. Set AVStream.time_base instead.
[mp4 @ 0x2d480c0] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
[mp4 @ 0x2d480c0] Using AVStream.codec.time_base as a timebase hint to the muxer is deprecated. Set AVStream.time_base instead.
[mp4 @ 0x2d480c0] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.



$ ffprobe mv1.mp4
ffprobe version N-79826-g64fd62d Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.1 (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) 20160413
  configuration: --prefix=/home/seaguest/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/home/seaguest/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/seaguest/ffmpeg_build/lib --enable-gpl --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 24.100 / 55. 24.100
  libavcodec     57. 39.100 / 57. 39.100
  libavformat    57. 36.100 / 57. 36.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 45.100 /  6. 45.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'mv1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.36.100
  Duration: 00:00:30.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 751 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480, 613 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Checking the setting section, crf=23.0 for both (the rest are exactly the same), but the output bitrate are different (the audio for calling code mode has a lot of noises), how is that possible?

Why the command line mode and use libav* library mode with same setting, but have different output?
What should I do to call libav* library to get lossless video conversion?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "noise"? It's ambiguous because while reading your question I was assuming video (graphic) noise (dots on the screen) but you said "hear" implying audio noise.

Comment: the audio has some noises, it seems the some part of audio becomes uncontinuous, the video performs much better than audio.

Comment: why is this a go question, actually why is this even on stackoverflow?